# Given a 4-dimensional array, how do I compute a percentile, excluding from consideration those whose corresponding 3rd and 4th indices are equal

Tags: python, numpy

I have a four dimensional array, M, which has size 10-by-8-by-4-by-4. I want to compute the 99th percentile, p, of its 1280 entries, excluding from consideration those values whose corresponding third and fourth indices are equal.

For example, I would include all matrices `M[:,:,2,3]` but I would exclude the matrices `M[:,:,i,i]` where i=0,1,2,3.

What would be the most efficient means for accomplishing this and how could I compute the indices of the form `[a,b,i,j]`, where 0<=a<=9, 0<=b<=7, 0<=i,j<=3 and where i and j are different and where `M[a,b,i,j]`>p ?

Comment: How are you defining percentile of a non-1d array?

Comment: By looking at all entries, not just along a single axis. For example, a=np.random.randn(2,3,4) has 24 elements and the percentile would be that of the flattened 24-by-1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is definitely to flatten the first two dimensions (maybe I missed something, but their distinction is redundant).

```
M = np.reshape(M, (80, 4, 4))
```

Then, you create a mask:

```
mask = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.eye(4), axis=0), 80, axis=0)
```

Then you create the masked array:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
masked_M = ma.masked_array(M, mask)
```

And now you can do anything with the masked array, including computing a percentile:

```
print(np.percentile(masked_M, 0.9))
```

Comment: Nice! And I see that ```indices=np.argwhere(masked_M>=p)``` where p is my percentile, gives me my corresponding indices.

Comment: Yeah, definitely, nice find!